# npm v9.5.1 is known not to run on Node.js v18.16.0

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nvm

I am using nvm to manage my Node.js versions. Recently, I installed Node.js version 18.16.0 using nvm, but when I try to use npm, I get the following error message:

`npm v9.5.1 is known not to run on Node.js v18.16.0`

I've searched for solutions online, but most of them seem to be related to installing a different version of Node.js. I'd like to stick with Node.js v18.16.0 if possible, since it's the version that works best with my project.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Node.js and npm using nvm, but I still get the same error message.

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error message, and how I can resolve it?

Comment: all you need to do is upgrade your npm version `npm install -g npm@latest`

Comment: @Fadedrifleman I'm also facing the same issue and this command also not working. Same error will appear on this command

Comment: @KaaL is it working for you?

Comment: @Rajeshkumar yes just update nvm to the latest version and you should be good.

Comment: @user18847228 trying to upgrade npm with `npm install -g npm@latest` also output same error

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This phenomenon is not a node problem.

It's an nvm version issue.

If you reinstall node 18.16.0 after updating nvm to the latest version, it works normally.

Comment: The combination of  nvm `1.1.9`, and node `18.16.0` (npm `9.5.1` ) works fine

Comment: @ChocoLi It's still not working for me.
$ nvm install v1.1.9
Version 1.1.9 is not available. If you are attempting to download a "just released" version,
it may not be recognized by the nvm service yet (updated hourly). If you feel this is in error and
you know the version exists, please visit http://github.com/coreybutler/nodedistro and submit a PR.

Answer (score 18):

I was stuck with an old version of NVM on Windows.

go to the [NVM-windows release page](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases) and get an installer that works for you.

then uninstall the old node/npm version to re-install it. See the steps below.

```bash
# run the following to re-install node and npm 
$ nvm list

  * 18.16.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    16.13.2

# get an old version
$ nvm use 16.13.2
Now using node v16.13.2 (64-bit)

# uninstall 
$ nvm uninstall 18.16.0
Uninstalling node v18.16.0... done

# reinstall 
$ nvm install 18.16.0
Downloading node.js version 18.16.0 (64-bit)... 
Extracting node and npm...
Complete
npm v9.5.1 installed successfully.


Installation complete. If you want to use this version, type

# run / use  it 
$ nvm use 18.16.0
Now using node v18.16.0 (64-bit)
```

Comment: Solved using this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with that version, found workaround:

- Using nvm I switched to my previous node version (16.19.0)
- I made `npm install -g npm@latest`
- I replaced `npm` catalog from version where it worked, so I put npm content from 16.19.0 into 18.16.0 `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.16.0\node_modules\npm\`
- Switch back with nvm to 18.16.0

Answer (score 0):

Basically it worked with the previous version which can remain by default at version `16.13.1`.

From there running `npm install -g npm@latest` update the local npm to the latest version.

- it was 9.8.5 in my case.

Answer (score 0):

: npm v9.6.7 is known not to run on Node.js v18.17.0.

becasue your are using old version of nvm please uninstall and try to reintasll then it will work fine..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u8ZF.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35396835)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).